# UITableView height same as content size

Tags: ios, uitableview

how can I have a UITableView of height equal to the height of it's content? (ie contentSize)

So far the solution I have is to create a constraint for the table height and `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` whenever I know the height has changed. And more, I can't set this constraint to the contentSize, but rather I need to calculate the height by hand adding the heights of the cells.

This makes it very cumbersome to deal with, especially when I have a table inside another table, or when I m not aware that the content size will change.

It seems such a normal use case to me, to have a table of the height of its contents, that I wonder if I m missing something obvious?

Comment: `UIStackView` sounds like better solution to solve this issue. Why are you using `UITableView` when you do not want to use built in `UIScrollView` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But what if I may want to use the same object with scroll in another context? Besides, conceptually I need a table, because it has cells. `UIStackView` seems like a bunch of views stacked.

Comment: If the table's height is the same as that of its contentSize.height, it will not scroll.. means no cell reusing. So you will need some max value for the contentSize and beyond which you will allow table's height > table.contentSize height. If this is the thing you are looking for then the best way may be is to have a observer for tableView's ContentSize. whenever it changes, do your checks and change the table's height (if required).

Comment: @dRAGONAIR how do you add that observer?

Comment: Martin simply create the `UIView`, place there everything from your cell and then reuse in `UITableViewCell` or use it directly in any other `UIViewController`. Tracking height change of `UITableVIew` its very bad practice in term of code quality and performance of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Add a observer in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

then implement the below

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let tableView = object as? UITableView {
        if tableView == self.tableView && keyPath == "contentSize" {
            // Now you know that the content size for self.tableView changed.
            // Do your frame updation here
        }
    }
}
```